# ASP.Net MVC 4 SimpleMembership "Re-Send Confirmation Email"

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I created a model for the "auto-generated" webpages_Membership table so that I can read the ConfirmationToken in case a user loses the confirmation email to be able to resend it. Here's my code in AccountModels.cs:

```
[Table("webpages_Membership")]
public class webpages_Membership
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
    public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
    public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
    public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
    public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTime> PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }
}

public class UsersContext : DbContext
{
    public UsersContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<webpages_Membership> webpages_Membership { get; set; }
}
```

Before I created this model, I was able to insert a single user on App_Start with the following line of code:

```
if (Membership.Provider.GetUser("admin", false) == null)
        {
            ((SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider).CreateUserAndAccount("admin", "bidchuck");
        }
```

After implementing this model, however, that line now throws an exception:

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'webpages_Membership' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.]
```

So, I suspect something about my model code to read data out of this table has conflicted with the way WebSecurity autogenerates the table and that is the cause of the exception. Can anyone explain how to change my model code so that WebSecurity can auto create the table in its own way?

Alternatively, suggest other ways for me to implement "Re-Send Confirmation Email"

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

You're telling EF explicitly that this is an identity column (i.e., that it should generate an id for you). However, the UserId is coming from ASP.NET membership, so your table should *not* in fact be generating an id.

Note: You'll have to migrate after removing that line.

**UPDATE**

1. Create a POCO to model the table:

   ```
   [Table("webpages_Membership")]
   public class Membership
   {
       public Membership()
       {
           Roles = new List<Role>();
           OAuthMemberships = new List<OAuthMembership>();
       }

       [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
       public int UserId { get; set; }
       public DateTime? CreateDate { get; set; }
       [StringLength(128)]
       public string ConfirmationToken { get; set; }
       public bool? IsConfirmed { get; set; }
       public DateTime? LastPasswordFailureDate { get; set; }
       public int PasswordFailuresSinceLastSuccess { get; set; }
       [Required, StringLength(128)]
       public string Password { get; set; }
       public DateTime? PasswordChangedDate { get; set; }
       [Required, StringLength(128)]
       public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
       [StringLength(128)]
       public string PasswordVerificationToken { get; set; }
       public DateTime? PasswordVerificationTokenExpirationDate { get; set; }

       public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }

       [ForeignKey("UserId")]
       public ICollection<OAuthMembership> OAuthMemberships { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Basically just model the fields in the table. This should cover everything, but things may have changed or different constraints may have been added. The `[Table("webpages_Membership")]` tells EF what table to look up in since the name or the class is not an exact match.
2. Hook up your POCO to a DbContext subclass. You'll want to use a different context than the one you're using for your actual mapped entities (the one you migrate with, update database with, etc.). The database initialization strategy is set at the DbContext level, so if you added this to the same one you're using for everything else, it will try to migrate it and you'll end up with nasty errors from EF.

   ```
   public class SimpleMembershipContext : DbContext
   {
       public SimpleMembershipContext()
           : base("name=YourConnectStringName")
       {
           // this tells EF to not worry about migrating or modifying the database
           Database.SetInitializer<SimpleMembershipContext>(null);
       }

       public DbSet<Membership> Memberships { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Replace the "YourConnectionStringName" with the name of the connection string for your project's database (in web.config). This could also be a totally different database if you're storing the membership stuff somewhere else, as well.

Now, with that, you can use it in your code like any other entity:

```
var membershipDb = new SimpleMembershipContext();
var someMember = membershipDb.Memberships.Find(userId);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Sounds like you know what you are talking about. I removed that line but am getting the same exact exception. My repro steps are to delete the database in SQL Server Object Explorer and press "play" in VS.

Comment: Or.. if you could just suggest how I get the ConfirmationToken out of the webpages_Membership table so that I can re-send the confirmation email, that would be FABULOUS!!!

Comment: Not sure why you'd be getting the same exception. You can also try adding the line back but using `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None` to force your will upon EF. As far as using webpages_Membership, just create a POCO to model the table, tell it to use the table with `[Table("webpages_Membership")]` or with Fluent API, and then add it to an untracked DbContext (add `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);` in the DbContext subclass' constructor). Then, you can use it as normal with EF.